# creating a jquery plugin that does not break the chain

Tags: jquery

I wrote this function to save headaches when I move CSS around(it converts CSS strings to objects). I would like to be able to use it as a drop in for the `.css()` function.

```
jQuery.fn.cCSS = function(css) {
    return this.each(function(){
    var css_obj = {};
    var tmx = "";
    ocss = css.split(";");
    $.each(ocss, function (index, elem){
        tmx = elem.trim().split(':');
        if (tmx[0].length > 0) 
            css_obj[tmx[0]] = tmx[1].trim();

    });
         return  $(this).css(css_obj);
        //return $;
    });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

My problem is when I use it in "fluent" notation I always get a null error.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addClass' of null

I'm a bit confused what has to be returned in order not to "break the chain"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into what line number that error is. I don't think it has anything to do with this function. The function itself worked for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/R8UtV/ << Demo

Especially since addClass isn't called, unless you're running it when you call the function?

ie

```
$('#test').cCSS('bleh...').addClass('foo');
```

Comment: I chained another function onto jsfiddle example and it works fine. In my code though any method after cCSS breaks execution with Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'xxxx' of null. I'll look deeper into it. I should have been clearer, the error happens when the function is called.

Comment: in the code you gave, you have an extra closing bracket. I don't know if that matters or if it was an accident

Comment: works fine, I have it in code 100s of times, used the stock css in one instance by mistake causing it to fail(the first one).

Answer (score 1):

You're returning `this.each(...)`!  The output of `.each()` is very likely just null.

Answer (score 0):

You want `return this`, after all, you're expecting to call the next function on the same object!